# Two lines in command area how to make a single line

Tags: vimrc

I have two lines in the command area. How to make a single line?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about `'cmdheight'`? It could also be that your terminal window is sized so that the last "line" is not big enough for a full line, so you get a partial. Please [edit] to clarify; your question is unclear.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble it's true 'cmdheight' tanks a lot.

Comment: feel free to self-answer if you were able to solve your issue!